# How can I reverse a value from a cell to save as my file name?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below that is obtaining the employee name from the A1 cell and setting it as part of the filename. The problem is the value in the excel sheet is written as 'first name last name'

Is there anyway I can format the value as 'last name, first name' using VBA?

```
Sub MyMacro()

    Dim Employee As String
    Dim FileN As String
    
    Employee = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    
    FileN = Employee & "_appraisals_" & Format(Range("A2"), "yyyy.mmm")
    
    ChDir "C:\Users\filepath\Desktop\PDFTest"
     
     ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FileN, Quality:=xlQualityStandard _
        , IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        False
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Are `Sheets("Sheet1")` and `ActiveSheet` the same worksheet? Is the code located in the workbook containing this worksheet(s)? I would rather define the whole file path than rely on `ChDir`: `FileN = "C:\Users\filepath\Desktop\PDFTest\" & Employee & "_appraisals_" & Format(Range("A2"), "yyyy.mmm") & ".pdf"`.

Comment: Please insert `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to enforce variable declaration (and indirectly catch typo like `Employee` and `EmployeeName`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. Use below code

```
    Employee = Split(Employee, " ")(1) & " " & Split(Employee, " ")(0)
```

Note: I assume first and last name is space delimited.